# Splitting list into sorted sublists

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

How can I divide a list [1,2,4,1,5,7,3,4,2,3] into a list of sublists that would be split at the values that break the sequence. For example a list [1,2,4,1,5,7,3,4,2,3] should yield a list of sublists like [[1,2,4],[1,5,7],[3,4],[2,3]].

Any ideas on this or suggestions how to resolve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, you have been really helpful, got lots of good information :)

Comment: Please mark homework questions as homework.

Answer (score 9):

Like Travis above, my first thought is to zip the list with its own tail:
However, it doesn't look like it quite works in this situation.  Not only is there not really a split function that does exactly what you want, but there's also the issue that you will lose an element either off the beginning or the end.  In lieu of a properly abstracted solution, take a look at this:

```
splitAscending :: Ord a => [a] -> [[a]]
splitAscending = foldr f [] where
    f x [] = [[x]]
    f x (y:ys) = if x < head y
    -- It's okay to call head here because the list y is
    -- coming from the summary value of the fold, which is [[a]].
    -- While the sum value may be empty itself (above case), it will
    -- never CONTAIN an empty list.  In general be VERY CAREFUL when
    -- calling head.
        then (x:y):ys -- prepend x to the first list in the summary value
        else [x]:y:ys -- prepend the new list [x] to the summary value
```

A quick and dirty solution, I hope it suits your needs

-- Also, this is my first post on Stack Overflow :)

Comment: I like this solution and think it's probably a bit more straightforward than mine, but it's certainly also *possible* to implement this with the tail-zipping approach (you just need to do something like `map (\ys -> fst (head ys) : map snd ys)` after `splitWhen`).

Answer (score 4):

Here's a hint: whenever you need to look at consecutive elements while processing a list, it's a good idea to start by zipping the list against its tail:

```
Prelude> let f xs = zip xs $ tail xs
Prelude> f [1,2,4,1,5,7,3,4,2,3]
[(1,2),(2,4),(4,1),(1,5),(5,7),(7,3),(3,4),(4,2),(2,3)]
```

Now you can use something like `splitWhen $ uncurry (>)` (where `splitWhen` is from [`Data.List.Split`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split)) to divide the list appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with 2 functions, one that splits the head while the first item is lower than the second, and another that takes the output of the function that splits the head, and concats the result of a recursive call to itself with the tail of the list.

```
splitList :: [Int] -> [[Int]]
splitList [] = []
splitList (x:xs) = ys : splitList zs
    where (ys,zs) = splitHead (x:xs)


splitHead :: [Int] -> ([Int], [Int])
splitHead [x] = ([x], [])
splitHead (x:y:xs)
    | x > y = ([x], (y:xs))
    | x <= y = (x:ys, zs)
    where (ys,zs) = splitHead (y:xs)
```

Comment: Reason for downvote please. I've tested my solution in WinHugs and works like a charm. Is it inefficient?

Answer (score 2):

Well, this isn't as clean as I would like it to be, but here it is.
Using package **split**: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split

```
:m+ Data.List.Split
Prelude Data.List.Split> let f ys = let ys' = zip ys (tail ys) in map (map fst) ((split . whenElt) (uncurry (>)) $ ys')
```

The braces could be very likely cleaned up here.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
asc [] = [[]]
asc (x:xs) = map reverse $ reverse $ foldl ins [[x]] xs
    where ins ((y:ys):yss) z | z > y = (z:y:ys) : yss
                             | otherwise = [z] : (y:ys) : yss
```

or

```
asc = map reverse.reverse.foldl ins [[]] 
      where ins [[]] z = [[z]]
            ins ((y:ys):yss) z | z > y = (z:y:ys) : yss
                               | otherwise = [z] : (y:ys) : yss
```

?